# Any idea how to import this data set?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following dataset:

https://github.com/felipe0216/fdfds/blob/master/sheffield_weather_station.csv

I know it is a csv, so I can use the pd.read_csv() function. However, if you look into the file it is not comma separated values nor a tab separated values, I am not sure what separation it has exactly. Any ideas about how to open it?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Yes! the answer he gave was perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("sheffield_weather_station.csv", comment="#", delim_whitespace=True)
```

You should first download the .csv file. You have to tell pandas that there will be comments and that there will just be spaces separating the columns. The amount of spaces do not matter.